# Angular matdatepicker is not displaying like it should

Tags: html, angular, package.json

I implement my html using matdatepicker but it's not displaying like how it should. The calendar icon is not showing up and the calendar only pops up when I click the arrow inside the input field.

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input type='date' 
          class="activity"
          matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

[Here is an image of what the datepicker looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcZl2.png)

Comment: try with remove this `type='type'`

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#connecting-a-datepicker-to-an-input

Comment: I suggest looking through https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples, and examining and exercising the StackBlitz demos.

Comment: I tried all the examples from angular material but that didnt fix anything

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjvyrkxnobva