# Material Design Date Picker Not working properly

Tags: html, angular, datepicker, material-design

This seems to be a common issue, but none of the posts I found helped me with this problem.  I've coded the angular date-picker into my html component and don't have anything in the css files, but I can't type in a date, the cursor in the input never appears and the calendar icon never appears.  I can click where the calendar icon is supposed to be and a calendar does pop up, but it doesn't have the title headers where you can change the month and year.

I'm pretty sure the code is right because when I tried it on stackblitz it worked fine.  My guess is there is something with the way I have my angular project setup.  Any ideas?

I've imported FormsModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule, MatIconModule, which I think is everything.

My package.json has @angular/material:^13.3.9, which should be the latest.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div *ngIf="isSignedIn">

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker" style="background:blue"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      

</div>
</html>

<div *ngIf="!isSignedIn">
    <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

This is what I've looked into and I have tried everything on these pages with no luck.

1. [Angular Material Date-Picker is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445006/angular-material-date-picker-is-not-working-properly)
2. [Angular matdatepicker is not displaying like it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524806/angular-matdatepicker-is-not-displaying-like-it-should)
3. [Angular Material Datepicker won't show in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771787/angular-material-datepicker-wont-show-in-the-page)
   4.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824227/angular-material-datetime-picker-not-showing-icons

Any more ideas?

[image: Screenshot of date-picker]

[image: Screenshot of calendar]

[image: elements screenshot (layers?)]
[image: matIconSuffix]

[image: elements above input]

Comment: open the tools F12 and see if you have a "layer" over the input (if you make cclikc and don't select the input this is the problem). BTW I'm not pretty sure if is `matSufix` -as you has wrote- or `matIconSuffix`

Comment: @Eliseo, can you specify what you mean by 'layer.  I attached a screenshot of the elements when I select on the box.  It looks like there is the input at the top, followed by the label and then the date-picker-toggle.  When I use matIconSuffix, it moves the calendar icon below the input field and it is still invisible, I still can't type in the input field and the blue background is removed.

Comment: If you have a div with background-transparent above the input, you can not "click" inside the input -you click in the "div"-

Comment: @Eliseo, I added a screenshots of the elements above the input element.  I guess the ng-tns-c121-0 is a transparent div?  How do I get rid of it.  I had my date-picker nested inside a div but its just to implement a login feature.  I added the full snippet of the html component.  Where is this transparent div coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: NOT, the ng-tns-s121-0 is related to you *ngIf. Try add in .css `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` to be sure is not problem about the .css. NOTE: Really I don't know what it's happened